# Poured Concrete, blocks or something else for single detached step

Tags: concrete, stairs, concrete-block, pavers, cinderblock

Good Afternoon,

I am redoing a patio at the front of our home and need some advice on how to handle a single step up to the existing front patio. Techo-Bloc calls for a pre-existing concrete step to be in place for the paver overlay if I make it match the rest of the patio base. If I were to pour a single concrete step here, would I need to put it footers and the whole nine yards? Could I use block or even cinder block for this? I’ve got 21” from the top of the existing patio to the excavated depth. The pavers are ~2” tall which gives me ~23” of distance to work with from finished patio height to excavated base. 6” compacted base, 1” sand, 2” pavers, 6” rise should work out.

I’m really just a little unsure on best practice for this single 6” tall x 12” deep x 12’ long single step.

Alternatively, I could just purchase single slab steps from Techo-Bloc, just looking for options and opinions.

We live in PA where the frost line is between 30 & 40”.

It appears that the concrete landing is ~6” thick (in blue) and the red portion is just a facade. No concrete behind that lip, just a bunch of rocks, dirt, etc but isn’t completely full. The yellow appears to the the portion that has ground contact.

When excavating we did remove ~12” of dirt where this is at.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the IRC governs you, on stairs without nosing the IRC calls for 11" minimum tread depth (see the exception under https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch03_SecR311.7.5.3). It's an ergonomic constraint, so I would respect it. If it's incompatible with your paver overlay, then just be aware that a building official could aggrieve you.

Comment: No constraint, so that is good to know. I can plan on at least that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concrete masonry units (cinder blocks) can be nice in that there's no wood form work. They leave behind an ugly surface that you would need to stucco to have them look nice, though, and the surface finish wouldn't match your concrete.

The importance of a foundation depends on your soil characteristics. See https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-4-foundations#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch04_SecR405.1 for the frost heave characteristics of the different soil classifications. By your 30" to 40" frost line, I suspect that you're not eager to get your foundation below the frost line. If you've got high frost heave potential or highly expansive soil, then I would consider digging a couple of holes down there (and probably reject the idea). If you've got bad soil, at least dowel into the substantial part of the existing porch's sidewalls to avoid gaps opening. If you've got good soil or even medium to good soil, then I'd cast the concrete on your base and not worry about foundation. I'd still dowel in this case if your paver layer is bedded in mortar, but this is pretty conservative (and it's probably a 150 USD detail if you don't own a rotary hammer). Loose pavers? I wouldn't bother with dowels.

I'm not sure about these "single slab steps," but my instinct is that prefabricated is too heavy or has joints that you probably want to avoid. Assuming that there are joints, is the product tongue-groove to avoid jump discontinuities? If the weight is manageable and the design avoids jump discontinuities, then that sounds like a good option too. I'd just be skeptical of bedding these in sand as opposed to mortar.

Comment: Help me out a bit here with your answer (take it easy on a concrete/structural noob). Since the portion of the patio in the middle is hollow, are you saying to drill into either end and tie in the step pour to the existing patio via 7” “hooks” on either end?

Comment: @Russ W., I assumed that you're attaching to a concrete front porch. Is that a wood front porch?

Comment: No you were correct. It’s concrete, but it’s not solid in that middle portion. It almost looks as if they poured the concrete on top of a bunch of junk, and once we excavated it looks like a lot of that junk came out the front. The slab appears to only be the top landing portion. Updated the question with another pictures and some additional words.

Comment: @Russ W. I've rewritten for your situation. There are better YouTube videos coaching you through soil classification than I can manage in text. I can offer a quick heuristic, though. Taking a sphere of your foundation soil in your hand with a diameter of about 1", can you roll it between your hands into a 1/4" diameter strand that holds together pretty well? If so then you have cohesive soil (silty to clayey), and that's bad news--it's susceptible to frost heave and changing in volume based on moisture availability.